# How to find the child control's IsEnabled property in ListBoxItem for Trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers, isenabled

I am trying to disable the ListBox item depending on IsEnabled property of ListBoxItem's content. Like in this code the button 1 has IsEnabled=False but list box item is selectable. I want to disable the selection if contents IsEnabled property is false. how should trigger search for the item content and its IsEnabled property.

```
<Grid>
      <ListBox>
         <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                  <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"  Value="False">
                     <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                  </Trigger>
               </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
         </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <ListBoxItem>
            <Button IsEnabled="False">1</Button>
         </ListBoxItem>
         <ListBoxItem>
            <Button>2</Button>
         </ListBoxItem>
         <ListBoxItem>
            <Button>3</Button>
         </ListBoxItem>         
      </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set `IsEnabled` on your `ListBoxItem` instead? It should disable the `Button` as well.

But that said, you could bind the `Button.IsEnabled` to `ListBoxItem.IsEnabled` using a `RelativeSource` binding, and set the `IsEnabled` property of the `ListBoxItem`, not the `Button` too

```
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}" />
```

If you're working with WPF, I'd highly recommend you look into the MVVM design pattern. It's well suited for WPF, and using it you would bind both the `ListBoxItem.IsEnabled` and `Button.IsEnabled` to the same property in the `DataContext`

Comment: thanks, but this is not what i want to achieve. I want to get the child control's IsEnabled property.
I am using MVVM, but i want use trigger in style which is in my resource dictionary.